# Commenting on Documentation?

Tags: support, documentation

I'm reading that you can comment on documentation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/docs-commenting), but when I'm looking at documentation I don't see the described button to leave a comment.

Am I missing something? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vim/4656/easter-eggs#t=201611080502151210038) is the page I'm trying to comment on.

Should I be using this, I'm not making a change just want clarification:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can currently comment on improvement requests and on proposed changes. For example, on [a proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/108911?filter-tags=c%23):

[image]

And on [an improvement request](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/108911?filter-tags=c%23):

[image]

Comment: Nice, was/is the beta invite only?

Comment: Actually, I think I might be wrong. Just a second, let me do some digging

Comment: Edited, @PhilipKirkbride. Looks like some of this has been deployed, see https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33744137#33744137.

Comment: That makes sense. In my case the top easter egg simply doesn't work with the latest vim. I'm not going to down-vote but I wish I could get some additional clarification.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride That sounds like a good thing to submit as an improvement request - there should probably be a version qualifier around that example.

Comment: It says 7.4 and up and I'm on 7.4.52 --- how do I submit an improvement request?

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride Use the flag symbol. See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKXwo.png).